# Kivy Buildozer python-for-android OpenSSL issue

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I have a Kivy app on Android that is supposed to send emails. Works fine on windows and linux, but when I run it on Android it gives me the following logcat:

```
I/python  (23377):  Traceback (most recent call last):

I/python  (23377):    File "/data/data/financas.org.test.financas/files/app/crystax_python/stdlib.zip/threading.py", line 923, in _bootstrap_inner

I/python  (23377):      self.run()

I/python  (23377):    File "/data/data/financas.org.test.financas/files/app/crystax_python/site-packages/jnius/__init__.py", line 53, in jnius_thread_hook

I/python  (23377):      return orig_thread_run(*args, **kwargs)

I/python  (23377):    File "/data/data/financas.org.test.financas/files/app/crystax_python/stdlib.zip/threading.py", line 871, in run

I/python  (23377):      self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

I/python  (23377):    File "main.py", line 108, in send_email

I/python  (23377):      server.starttls()

I/python  (23377):    File "/data/data/financas.org.test.financas/files/app/crystax_python/stdlib.zip/smtplib.py", line 756, in starttls

I/python  (23377):      raise RuntimeError("No SSL support included in this Python")

I/python  (23377):  RuntimeError: No SSL support included in this Python
```

The code looks like this:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread

        [...]

        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        msg['From'] = fromaddr
        msg['To'] = toaddr
        msg['Subject'] = " ".join(subj)

        body = body

        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(fromaddr, password)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
        server.quit()
```

I have included openssl in the spec file requirements:

```
requirements = python3crystax,kivy,openssl
```

I have tried clean installing buildozer, updating it... The whole deal. I'm running out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, it seems python3 still doesn't have a working openssl option:

https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/558

Comment: Rewrote the code with python2 and now it works. Leaving the info here in case someone searches for it.